# introducir una fecha en angular mediante input

Tags: date

Estoy intentando introducir una fecha, mediante un imput con type="date" en mi código en angular.
En principio no he tenido ningún problema y funciona pero NO con SAFARI, que no muestra ni el calendario.
También he probado con DataPiker pero me encuentro con lo mismo.
¿Alguna idea?
Utilizo un formControlName no ngModel

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Creo que Safari so soporta `type="date"`

Comment: Estas usando `DatePicker`? Si es asi deberias de incluir tu codigo

Comment: Safari no es compatible con los tipos date si es reconocible pero no se muestra ni UI y si esta correcta la información espero eso te ayude usa opciones de librerías diferentes para mostrar la Ui correctamente en safari! es mi sugerencia